# Teradata sql query - compare current day value with previous day value

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have 3 columns(CustomerId, Amount, ProcessDate) in a table (Customer).

Values are inserted daily in this table.

I want to get all the rows whose current day Amount is greater than previous day Amount.

CustomerId  Amount  Process_date

**1         20      12/05/2021**

2           30      12/05/2021

**1         40      13/05/2021**

2           25      13/05/2022

We have to print (1         40      13/05/2021) as 20 (previous day amount) is smaller than 40 (next day amount).

Query which I tried :-

```sql
select b.customerId, b.amount, b.process_date from customer a
 join (select customerId, amount, process_date from customer where process_date = current_date ) as b
on
a.customerId = b.customerId and 
a.process_date = current_date - 1 and a.amount < b.amount
```

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, and what have you tried?

Comment: Seems like you may want LAG function and QUALIFY clause. Try to give a simple example with a few rows of data, what you have tried (and any error messages or results that don't meet the requirement), and what was desired as output.

Comment: Append `qualify Amount > lag(Amount) over (partition by CustomerId order by ProcessDate)` to your current select.